# Is there a semantic way in HTML5 and WAI-ARIA to describe "Toggleable Help Content"?

Tags: html, seo, semantic-markup, wai-aria

I'm trying to find the semantically correct way to describe an HTML element that represent a way to get help (e.g. help icon) and its help content. 
I tried to search on this topics but searching help on help isn't an easy business. Here would be a simple example of what I have in mind (using a simple script to show/hide the help content as well as leveraging the "title" attribute):

```
<div>
    Please enter your password 
    <a class="help" title="Your password must have 5 characters">
        <img src="/images/help.svg" alt="">
    </a>
    <span class="helpText displayNone">
        Your password must have 5 characters.
    </span>
    <input type="password>
</div>
```

Is there a better way to represent this (in this format). The idea is to have an accessible and SEO friendly way to describe "toggleable help content".

The question is about **HTML/HTML5** and **WAI-ARIA attributes** (not JavaScript) - I'm looking for the best element representation of my example (if such concept exists).

Comment: Get help? What do you mean

Comment: In the example I provided the idea is to have an "help icon" and when you click on the help icon it provides help in a given context. The context given in my example is for a password but it could be any field.

Comment: Use the jquery on() method with .style.visibility = "hidden";

Comment: @Artsicle I know out to achieve this, even without jQuery. I'm asking from a semantic perspective, are there HTML elements and attributes that we should use for that sort of context?

Comment: idk, your choice.

Comment: @Artsicle So that's why I'm trying to figure out... if there is more appropriate elements to use than what I thought could be good. Solving the problem is easy, I could do it with almost any elements. I'm just wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: jquery is lightweight enough.

Comment: @Artsicle I think you're missing the point. This is not about jQuery or having simple click events. This is about which HTML5 elements should be best used in this sort of context considering SEO and ARIA in play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this question is larger than you intend based on your markup. First let's clean up your example so there are appropriate semantic and structural elements in place that also make this accessible to users:

```
<div>
  <label for="pwd">Please enter your password</label>
  <input type="password" id="pwd">
</div>
```

That makes for an accessible field. No script, no ARIA. Just a `<label>` that is properly associated with the field.

Now you want to offer some help to the user and still associate it with the field.

First, do not use an anchor. That tells users of assistive technology that it will take them away from the page and they may not want to click or activate the control. Use `<button>`.

Then you can use ARIA to associate that tip with the field. In this case `aria-describedby` will be announced along with the field.

You also need to fill out the `alt` attribute, or your image will not be announced to a screen reader user at all.

The best ARIA role to use in this context is the `role=tooltip` ([read more in the ARIA spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#tooltip)).

Here is one way you could approach it:

```
<div>
  <label for="pwd">Please enter your password</label>
  <button><img src="/images/help.svg" alt="Help"></button>
  <span id="pwd-tip" role="tooltip">Your password must have 5 characters.</span>
  <input type="password" id="pwd" aria-describedby="pwd-tip">
</div>
```

You can use CSS to determine if the button has focus and display the following sibling span (`button:focus + span`) if you must avoid script, but that is sloppy. You can use script to toggle a class on the `button` which uses similar CSS to then display the `span`.

You can put the text into the `<label>` and hide it by using a CSS off-screen technique, meaning it will always be announced to screen readers and then you can dump the `aria-describedby`.

Frankly, you can skin this a few different ways. Check out the keyboard interactions you must consider also over at the [ARIA Practices description for a tooltip](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/#tooltip).

However, for the most part you are better off making your help text always visible (especially if you want to satisfy the nebulous notion of SEO). In a vacuum I would just put this text in the `<label>` and be done with it.

Comment: Great answer - I wish help text could always be visible but sometime it would just kills the design. One drawback with your solution on the other hand is that you cannot leverage the mouseover effect of the title attribute but who uses that nowadays?

Comment: @aadrian Actually back to my comment, if you add title on your button attribute or image, it could provide the same capabilities as my original answer. Of course you would probably need to store that repeated text in a variable somewhere...

Comment: You can create a mouseover effect via CSS (sloppy code): `button:hover + span::after, button:focus + span::after {content: attr(data-text);position:absolute;...}`. For a better example but different implementation, check this: http://codepen.io/aardrian/pen/ENJdjN?editors=1100 Further, please [do not use a `title` attribute](https://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2012/01/html5-accessibility-chops-title-attribute-use-and-abuse/).